# Facebook and Twitter likes number in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, facebook-graph-api, twitter

Here's my code inside my `functions.php`:

```
function facebook_likes($link){
    $obj = json_decode( file_get_contents( 'http://graph.facebook.com/?id='.$link ) );
    $likes = $obj->shares;
    return $likes;
}

function twitter_shares($link) {
    $obj = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url='.$link));
    $tweets = $obj->count;
    return $tweets;
}
```

When I try to display the numbers in my `index.php`, I get the full url instead:

```
<p> Social: facebook (<?php facebook_likes(the_permalink()); ?>), twitter(<?php twitter_shares(the_permalink()); ?>) </p>
```

Output in my html is like this: `Social: facebook(url), twitter(url)`

where url is the `permalink` of the post. What am I doing wrong? The code seems too obvious to screw up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of problems with this code:

1. `the_permalink()` will output the url directly. It will not return anything that can be passed to another method. You should use `get_permalink` instead.
2. Conversely, your functions return a value, but your usage does not echo the value.
3. This is a poor implementation. Your page load depends on these two urls returning responses. If they do not, your page will load very slowly as it will wait for the requests to fail. Additionally, you will likely run into limits how often you can query the urls. You probably want to stick with the facebook/twitter widgets for this.